# How can sbteclipse-plugin error be solved

Tags: eclipse, sbt

Giving error while installing sbt:

[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.1.0: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?} like so'''
*/

Comment: typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.1.0
typesafe-ivy-releases: tried repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] =sbt-plugin-releases: tried https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn] /home/hadoop1/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin_2.12_1.0/5.1.0/sbtec

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this issue , It is only arising due to plugin miss-match. So you can add these plugins in order to run sbt-eclipse. It is for ubuntu.
put this plugins in your .sbt/1.0/plugins directory

For sbt 1.x:

Add the following to your ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/gpg.sbt file:

addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "2.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")

For sbt 0.13.x:

Add the following to your ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/gpg.sbt file:

addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "2.0.0")